# How to convert an interval type to days (int)? Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, datetime, apache-spark-sql

I have the following doubt:
In the query I'm performing in spark sql, I'm not finding a function that makes me convert the interval type, which is in hours, into days, and then convert it to integer. The days_after_order column is ok, but I need to change the datatype of the days_between_order column. How to solve?

```py
test = spark.sql(f'''
SELECT cds, 
id_cl, 
cd_prod, 
dt_em, 
datediff(current_date(),dt_em) as days_after_order,
(dt_em - LAG(dt_em) OVER (PARTITION BY cds, id_cl, cd_prod ORDER BY dt_em)) as days_between_order
FROM data
''')
```

And the results obtained:

| cds | id_cl | cd_prod | dt_em | days_after_order | days_between_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 58189 | 2022-01-10 00:00:00 | 246 | null |
| 10 | 1 | 78889 | 2022-05-16 00:00:00 | 120 | null |
| 10 | 1 | 38850 | 2022-09-11 00:00:00 | 2 | null |
| 10 | 1 | 37372 | 2022-01-23 00:00:00 | 233 | null |
| 10 | 1 | 43381 | 2022-01-23 00:00:00 | 233 | null |
| 10 | 1 | 43381 | 2022-09-11 00:00:00 | 2 | 5544 hours |
| 10 | 1 | 13666 | 2022-01-11 00:00:00 | 245 | null |
| 10 | 1 | 13666 | 2022-02-26 00:00:00 | 199 | 1104 hours |
| 10 | 1 | 33603 | 2022-06-27 00:00:00 | 78 | null |
| 10 | 1 | 33603 | 2022-06-27 00:00:00 | 78 | 0 seconds |

The printSchema:

```
root
 |-- cds: long (nullable = true)
 |-- id_cl: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- cd_prod: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- dt_em: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- days_after_order: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- days_between_order: interval (nullable = true)
```

When I convert the timestamp column to date, these are the results I get:

| cds | id_cl | cd_prod | dt_em | days_after_order | days_between_order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 1 | 58189 | 2022-01-10 00:00:00 | 246 | null |
| 10 | 1 | 78889 | 2022-05-16 00:00:00 | 120 | null |
| 10 | 1 | 38850 | 2022-09-11 00:00:00 | 2 | null |
| 10 | 1 | 37372 | 2022-01-23 00:00:00 | 233 | null |
| 10 | 1 | 43381 | 2022-01-23 00:00:00 | 233 | null |
| 10 | 1 | 43381 | 2022-09-11 00:00:00 | 2 | 7 months 19 days |
| 10 | 1 | 13666 | 2022-01-11 00:00:00 | 245 | null |
| 10 | 1 | 13666 | 2022-02-26 00:00:00 | 199 | 1 months 15 days |
| 10 | 1 | 33603 | 2022-06-27 00:00:00 | 78 | null |
| 10 | 1 | 33603 | 2022-06-27 00:00:00 | 78 | 0 seconds |

Answer (score 1):

change (dt_em - LAG(dt_em) to "datediff(dt_em,LAG(dt_em)"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).